# Performance issue while groupby.shift

Tags: python, pandas, performance, pandas-groupby

Test code:

```
SIZE_MULT = 5
data = np.random.randint(0, 255, size=10**SIZE_MULT, dtype='uint8')
index = pd.MultiIndex.from_product(
            [list(range(10**(SIZE_MULT-1))), list('ABCDEFGHIJ')],
            names = ['d', 'l'])        
test = pd.DataFrame(data, index, columns = ['data'])
test.head()
test['data'].dtype
```

**Output**:

```
        data
d   l   
0   A   137
    B   156
    C   48
    D   186
    E   170

dtype('uint8')
```

And suppose we want group by 0-level of index and shift each group (shift step = 2, for example).

```py
%%time
shifted = test.groupby(axis=0, level=[0]).shift(2)
print(shifted['data'].dtype)
```

**Output:**

```
float64
CPU times: user 9.43 ms, sys: 56 µs, total: 9.49 ms
Wall time: 8.29 ms
```

Now to the problem: if we want to preserve our dtype 'uint8', we have to get rid of `None`s, and set our fill value with 0, for example. But we will get HUGE time of code execution now:

```py
%%time
shifted = test.groupby(axis=0, level=[0]).shift(2, fill_value = 0)
shifted.head()
print(shifted['data'].dtype)
```

**Output:**

```
uint8
CPU times: user 5.9 s, sys: 38.4 ms, total: 5.94 s
Wall time: 5.89 s
```

So the question is why this is so long? If we take 1st shifted dataframe without `fill_value`, and add few code lines to achieve same result:

```py
%%time
shifted = test.groupby(axis=0, level=[0]).shift(2)
shifted.fillna(0, inplace=True)
shifted = shifted.astype(np.uint8)
print(shifted['data'].dtype)
```

**Output:**

```
uint8
CPU times: user 9.64 ms, sys: 3.68 ms, total: 13.3 ms
Wall time: 11.3 ms
```

It will add only few ms, not 5 seconds.

**EDIT:** corresponding github [issue](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/26615)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [source code](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/v0.24.2/pandas/core/groupby/groupby.py#L2011-L2019) the issue is that with a fill value specified it uses a slow apply call. Without a fill value, it's able to use the much faster cythonized result:

#### Code from the link:

```
def shift(self, periods=1, freq=None, axis=0, fill_value=None):
    #...
    if freq is not None or axis != 0 or not isna(fill_value):
        return self.apply(lambda x: x.shift(periods, freq,
                                            axis, fill_value))

    return self._get_cythonized_result('group_shift_indexer',
                                       self.grouper, cython_dtype=np.int64,
                                       needs_ngroups=True,
                                       result_is_index=True,
                                       periods=periods)
```

So in this case, I would use `.fillna()` after.